# group by in Linq to entities

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table with two columns, state and loan like this

```
State  loan

NJ     100
CA     200
NJ     150
CT     300
CT     100
```

I want to group the loan by state using linq. I have done this but it is not working

```
var query = from address in context.data_vault.ToList()
group address by address.STATE into addressGroup
select new
{
    State = addressGroup.Key,
    count = addressGroup.Count()
};
```

I need to page the results as well.

Please suggest me how to do it

Comment: What do you mean when you say `it is not working`?

Comment: it is giving error. The data source does not support server-side data paging.

Answer (score 1):

To page the result, just use [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx):

```
int n = 3;
int pageSize = 10;
var pagedQuery = query.Skip(n * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: Do I need to write this code in page load or grid selected index change ?